# edit csv with python

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I would need to know if it is possible to edit a csv file to transform a single line into several lines.
let me explain, I have this line in a csv file:

**A**

0,EMKR,10,DATE,CLOSE/LAST,VOLUME,OPEN,HIGH,LOW[{'DATE:'01/14/2022','close':'$6.24','volume':'255.222'...},{''DATE:'01/13/2022','close':'$6.24','volume':'255.222'...} (all this in row 1)

I would need to come so the csv file:

**B**

1. 0,EMKR,10,DATE,CLOSE/LAST,VOLUME,OPEN,HIGH,LOW (row1)
2. {'DATE:'01/14/2022','close':'$6.24','volume':'255.222'...} (row2)
3. {''DATE:'01/13/2022','close':'$6.24','volume':'255.222'...} (row3)

is it possible to modify it in this way? if yes, how do you do it?

thank you

**UPDATE**

I put below the code I'm using

```
import request
import json
import pandas as pd
import csv
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

url = ('https://api.nasdaq.com/api/quote/EMKR/historical?assetclass=stocks&fromdate=2022-01-01&limit=10000&todate=2022-01-17')

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

y = response.text

info = json.loads(y)

ordine = (json.dumps(info['data'], indent=0, sort_keys=True))

df = pd.json_normalize(info['data'])
df.to_csv("TRY.csv")
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It would be nice if you can provide something that you've tried, see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Pretty much anything is possible.

Comment: Yes, though I would caution you against it as the result will be **much** harder to use than just a csv. If you want to restructure your data a bit then building a list of dictionaries with sub lists in them and then using `json.dumps()` might give you better usability

Comment: the fact that I extract the data in JSON, from JSON I convert them to CSV (format I need) only that the data is saved to me all in a single row but I need each row to have its own data

Comment: Can you edit your question and add a sample of the returned JSON?